# Set one variable in another batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to set a variable in another batch file, if it exsists. But it works only localy in the sub batch file. How can I fix this problem?

Main.bat:

```
SET TEMP=""
IF EXIST SUB.bat (
    CALL SUB.bat 
      REM Returns: TEMP="" IN MAIN
      ECHO %TEMP% IN MAIN
) ELSE (
      SET TEMP="DEFAULT VALUE"
)
```

Sub.bat:

```
SET TEMP="OTHER VALUE"
REM Returns: TEMP="OTHER VALUE" IN SUB
ECHO %TEMP% IN SUB
```

Output by calling Main.bat:

```
TEMP="OTHER VALUE" IN SUB
TEMP="" IN MAIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

Your test is incorrect. Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Try using `CALL ECHO %%TEMP%%` to display the altered value and look up "delayedexpansion" for endless SO items on this frequently-encountered subject.

Second issue - which impinges on the first.

`TEMP` and `TMP` are special variablenames which specify the location of a temporary-files directory. Best not to change them as unexpected results may ensue. Use another variablename.

Comment: But the variable is empty, if I use it in another Batch file, which has been called by the Main.bat. Why?

Comment: Without the exact code you are using, any response would be a guess unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know what I did or if I did anything but it works now -.- THX!